# How can I get the real table name of the entity in EF, even if I modify the name of the entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I get the real table name of the entity in EF, even if I modify the name of the entity.
I would like to extend a bulk delete feature。

Comment: If you are trying to create a bulk delete there already is one someone wrote, take a look at EntityFramework.Extended in nuget

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this ought to work:

```
string GetTableName()
{
    Type t = this.GetType();
    var tableAttributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true);
    if (tableAttributes.Length == 0)
        return t.Name;
    else
        return ((TableAttribute)tableAttributes[0]).Name;
}
```

Basically, if the class is Marked with the [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), you can get the real table name from that. If its not marked, the default for EF is to use the same name as the class.